# change the style of numbering the theorem, definition in sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

`enter code here`Could you help me please to create a paper which appears in the following way:

**The Newton's Law** - section

**1 Definition** - \begin{definition} \end{definition}

**2 Theorem** - \begin{theorem} \end{theorem}

**The conjecture of Poincare** - section

**1 Definition** - \begin{definition} \end{definition}

**2 Theorem** - \begin{theorem} \end{theorem}

For me it is hard to create different sections which have same numbering, and also to put the number in front of the theorem or of the definition. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{variations}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsthm}
\swapnumbers 
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem} 
\let\origsection\section 
\renewcommand\section{\setcounter{definition}{0}\origsection}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lem\u a}

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolar}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Not\u a}

%\theoremstyle{definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Consecin\c t\u a}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Exemplul}
\newtheorem*{acknowledgements}{Observa\c{t}ie}
```

Comment: Will the sections themselves be numbered, and should the section's number be included in the number of the definitions and theorems?

Comment: the section's number won't be included in the number of definitions and theorems

Comment: If you replace the instances of `[theorem]` with `[definition]`, you'll get what you're looking for. Also, do remember to load the `hyperref` package *last*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve your objective would be to (i) make sure that the `definition` and `theorem` environments share the same counter and (ii) redefine the `\section` command in a way that resets this counter to 0, regardless of whether the sections are numbered or not. The example below does these things, while using the `amsthm` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsthm}
\swapnumbers % place definition/theorem number *before* name
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem} % link the counters
\let\origsection\section % save the original section definition
\renewcommand\section{\setcounter{definition}{0}\origsection}

\begin{document}
\section*{Newton's Law}
\begin{definition}[Here we go] bla bla bla\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}[Deep thoughts] more bla bla \end{theorem}

\section*{The Poincaré Conjecture}
\begin{definition}[More to say] bla bla bla\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}[Random thoughts] Still more bla bla \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't work. I will add in my question the beginning of my latex program.

Comment: It's crucial to key all theorem-like environments to the same counter. In my answer, it's the counter of the `definition` counter. What happens if you key all environments to the counter named `definition` (rather than, say, `theorem`).